# Pegando tempo do sistema em C

Tags: c, time

Quero pegar o tempo de início e fim de um `for`. Ex.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  int i, j;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );
  for (j = 0; j < 10; j ++)
        for (i = 0; i < 138763431; i ++);
  printf ( "\nCurrent local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```

Já estou usando o `GetTickCount()` para segundos. Daria pra manipular mas do jeito que já tentei utilizando o `time.h` a hora é fixa quando chamo em qualquer lugar do meu `main`.

Comment: Não entendi por que não usa `GetTickCount`.

Comment: Coloca o que você fez e o que deu errado.

Comment: porque obrigatoriamente tenho que mostrar o tempo de inicio e o tempo final. vou usar o GetTickCount para mostrar os segundos entre esse tempo.

Comment: @bigown editado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma " simples" de calcular a diferença de tempo usando pouco código

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int arc, char *argv[])
{
 clock_t t1, t2; // duas variáveis para guardar o registro clock

 t1 = clock(); // pega esse instante

 int i;

 for(i = 0;i < 500000 ;i++)
 {
      int x = 90; 
 }

 t2 = clock(); // pega esse

 // tira a diferença e divide por 1000000.0F

 float diff = (((float)t2 - (float)t1) / 1000000.0F ); // mile segundos
 printf("%f",diff);

 return 0;
 }
```

Esse [projeto](http://ideone.com/cGKlGe) faz uma demostração do uso desse calculo

Comment: Porque float? Fica bem melhor com double: `double diff = (((double)t2 - (double)t1) / 1000000.0);`

Comment: Importante: a única forma correta de saber quantas unidades de clock tem em um segundo é usar a macro [`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/CLOCKS_PER_SEC).

Answer (score 3):

Veja se resolve o que você deseja com o [código que achei no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17252934/221800).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys\timeb.h> 

int main() { 
    struct timeb start, end;
    int diff;
    int i = 0;
    ftime(&start);

    while(i++ < 999) {
        /*gastando tempo*/
        printf(".");    
    }

    ftime(&end);
    diff = (int) (1000.0 * (end.time - start.time) + (end.millitm - start.millitm));

    printf("\nGastou %u milisegundos\n", diff);
    return 0;
}
```

É possível destrinchar o `timeb`. Veja [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677047/221800):

```
void getCurrTimeString(TCHAR* mytime) {
    _timeb myTime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    _ftime64_s( &myTime );
    time_t rawtime = myTime.time;
    unsigned short myMillis = myTime.millitm;
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    _stprintf(mytime,_T("%d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d"),
        (1900+timeinfo->tm_year),
        (timeinfo->tm_mon+1),
        timeinfo->tm_mday,
        timeinfo->tm_hour,
        timeinfo->tm_min,
        timeinfo->tm_sec,
        myMillis);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Library/Time.c).

Comment: já ajudou com os milisegundos, mas o que quero mesmo é printar o tempo antes e depois do loop.

Comment: @Josinaldo Você não consegue montar isso com o `start` e `end`?

Comment: daria sim se o 'programa' fosse direto, no meu caso o loop é o usuário que digita a quantidade, e tem menu onde ficaria oncioso esperando o usuário, bem, até onde eu sei não teria como calcular assim, se tiver uma saída :/